# Moving through toggle buttons using arrow keys

Tags: wxpython, togglebutton

As a follow-up question to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462415/only-one-button-in-a-panel-with-multiple-togglebuttons-changes-color-wxpython/31464327#31464327) I was wondering if there is a way to navigate through multiple toggle buttons using the arrow keys?

My program needs to know which toggle button the user is currently selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution. I know this is not a very "pythonic" or even conventionally good solution but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx
k = 0
Buttons = []
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, title = "Gonna Get Them Cursor Keys Workin'")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.flags_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.sizer.Add(self.flags_panel)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer,wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT)
        self.flags = Flags(self.flags_panel, [8,12])#,rows = 12, columns = 8, radius = 10, hspace = 25, vspace = 25, x_start = 15, y_start = 15
        self.flags.Show()

class Flags (wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,panel, num_flags = []):#,rows = 0,columns = 0,radius = 0, hspace = 0, vspace = 0,x_start = 0, y_start = 0
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,panel,-1, size = (350,700))

    num_rows = num_flags[0]
    num_columns = num_flags[1]
    x_pos_start = 10
    y_pos_start = 10
    xy_coords = []
    i = x_pos_start
    j = y_pos_start
    buttons = []
    self.position_tuple_array = []
    for i in range (num_columns):
        buttons.append('toggle button')
    self.ButtonValue = False
    for button in buttons:
        index = 0
        while index != 15: 
            i += 25
            index += 1
            self.position_tuple_array.append((i,j))
        xy_coords.append((i,j))
        j += 15
        i = 10
    print self.position_tuple_array
    global Buttons
    for k in range (len(self.position_tuple_array)):
        self.Button = wx.ToggleButton(self,-1,size = (10,10), pos = self.position_tuple_array[k])
        self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,self.OnKeyPress)
        Buttons.append(self.Button)
        self.Button.SetFocus()
        self.Button.Show()
    print Buttons
    #That text crap below goes here

def OnKeyPress(self,event):
    button = event.GetEventObject()
    keycode = event.GetKeyCode() #New Code
    print keycode
    global Buttons

    global k
    if k > len(Buttons):
        k = 0
    elif k < 0:
        k = len(Buttons) - 1
    if keycode == wx.WXK_LEFT:
        print "YOU MOVED LEFT"
        k -= 1
        Buttons[k].SetFocus()
    elif keycode == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
                    print "YOU MOVED RIGHT"
                    k += 1
                    Buttons[k].SetFocus()

            elif keycode == wx.WXK_UP:
                    print "YOU MOVED UP"
                    k -= 15
                    Buttons[k].SetFocus()

            elif keycode == wx.WXK_DOWN:
        print "YOU MOVED DOWN"
        k += 15
        Buttons[k].SetFocus()
    elif keycode == wx.WXK_RETURN:#End of New Code
        if not self.ButtonValue:
            button.SetBackgroundColour('#fe1919')
            self.ButtonValue = True
        else:
            button.SetBackgroundColour('#14e807')
            self.ButtonValue = False
    print self.position_tuple_array[k]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If you are on windows just use EVT_CHAR_HOOK instead of EVT_KEY_DOWN.....worked for me.

Comment: Why not use the tab button? That's what most people use to navigate between widgets

Comment: It's simply because the user needs to move through these buttons as they see fit whereas using tab you can only go from left to right. I am looking up how to use tab to navigate out of this panel completely and into another one but I haven't been able to do that yet. Sort of like making the parent regain focus from the child.

Comment: What about up and down? The point of this UI was to make the user pretty much use only arrow keys and enter for maximum usability.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Hey Mike I was having some serious trouble when I change  the i variable that determines where each button goes. For me the first line of buttons is offset a little too much to the left. Any idea why this would happen or how to fix it?

Comment: Actually, messing around with the code, it seems that the <for> loop before the position setting changes the value of i, thus i always starts at a value that is equal to the length of buttons