# Can multiple widgets receive focus at once in wxPython?

Tags: widget, wxpython, focus

I am trying to make four buttons in a panel receive focus at once. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want it for? Perhaps there is another way to accomplish your goal with a little differnt design.

Comment: @RobinDunn I have posted the application that I am trying to use this for [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660338/moving-through-toggle-buttons-using-arrow-keys] here. Essentially, I want the toggle buttons to receive focus in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. wxPython does not support setting focus to multiple widgets at once.